# How could I make a switch "animate" properly when its property changes in a FutureBuilder?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have a switch that changes a value in a database. The future in the FutureBuilder is to get the switch's current value (I do this so that if the value fails to update the switch will still be the correct value). When I switch the switch, I call setState to change the switch's value and the value on the database. A side effect of this is that the switch and FutureBuilder is rebuilt every time the switch is used, causing the switch to flicker.

Is there a way to implement the switch in the FutureBuilder so that it properly does the "switch" animation?

Here is my switch widget:

```dart
dynamic currentValue = false;

  Future<void> _changeValue(String optionName, dynamic value) async {
    await widget.db
        .collection('CameraSettings')
        .document(optionName)
        .updateData({optionName: value});
  }

  Future<dynamic> _getValue(String optionName) async {
    DocumentSnapshot value =
        await widget.db.collection('CameraSettings').document(optionName).get();
    return value.data[optionName];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder(
      future: _getValue(widget.optionName),
      builder: (context, snapshot) {
        if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
          currentValue = snapshot.data;
          return Switch(
            value: currentValue,
            onChanged: (bool newVal) {
              setState(
                () {
                  currentValue = newVal;
                  _changeValue(widget.optionName, newVal);
                },
              );
            },
          );
        } else {
          return Switch(value: currentValue, onChanged: null);
        }
      },
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get data in init state, so it will not called again when you call setState.

create a variable which check data is arrived or not.

```
bool isDataloaded = false;
bool currentValue = false;
```

now call _getValue in init state.

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _getValue(widget.optionName).then((snapshot) {
      setState(() {
        currentValue = snapshot;
        isDataloaded = true;
      });
    });
  }
```

Now build widget

```
return Container(
    child: isDataloaded ? Switch(
        value: currentValue,
        onChanged: (bool newVal) {
          setState(
            () {
              currentValue = newVal;
              _changeValue(widget.optionName, newVal);
            },
          );
        },
      ): Switch(value: currentValue, onChanged: null)
 );
```